# Probabilities of a complex dice-game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

**Intro**

I am currently developing a board-game and am trying to balance things around my dice-mechanic, but for that I need the probabilities of the outcomes and after countless fruitless hours of calculation I am turning to this community.

I apologize for improper grammar and technical terms, since English is not my mother tongue.

**The Mechanic**

A player has X (usually between 1 and 10) number of six-sided-dice which are labeled:

- three times: **1**
- two times: **2**
- one time: **4**

After the player throws the dice, they group all ones together in one pool, all twos together in another pool and all fours together in yet another pool.
They then select one of those pools, to make a play in the game.

Relevant is here, that the value of a pool is determined by the sum of all its faces, als well as the total number of dice in the pool. Higher is better. So in some cases it is more relevant to pick the pool with the highest summ, while sometimes the pool with the higher number of total dice is more helpful.

**An Example**

I throw 5 dice and the come up: *1, 1, 1, 2, 4*. So I group them up in Pool_1={1,1,1}, Pool_2={2} and Pool_4={4}.

Pool_4 has the highest sum with 1x4=4, but Pool_1 has the highest number of dice with 3. Depending on my ingame situation I would choose one or the other, while Pool_2 in this case offers no benefit.

**My Question**

When I throw *X* dice, what is the probability of …

1. reaching or exceeding the sum of *A*, when I pick the pool with the highest sum?
2. reaching or exceeding the amount *B* of dice in a pool, when I pick the pool with the highest number of dice?
3. reaching or exceeding the amount *C* of dice in a pool, when I pick the pool with the highest sum?

**Outro**

I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve this conundrum, so I could continue working on my project, to make it as fun and fair as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: I have not think of any smart way to do this except the brute force way to enumerate all the cases. The model is like the follow: The number of dice in the pool, $(N_1, N_2, N_4) \sim \text{Multinomial}(x; 1/2, 1/3, 1/6)$, assuming all dice are fair and mutually independent. After this you try to use computer software to help you to list out the cases.

Comment: @BGM You might be right, in that it is more efficient in this case to burn processing-power instead of brain-power. Thank you for the suggestion!